# AFNetworking with put and request body

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking-2

I've tried to send put with body, but in response I've got a

```
JSON: {
errorr = "BAD json format";
success = 0;
}
```

I've tried to use the same string(json array) as in my code for Rest Web Service Client and it works fine, but not in my app

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: carID, @"product_id", firstname.text, @"firstname", surname.text, @"lastname", phone.text, @"telephone", email.text, @"email", orderWithUserInfo, @"options", nil];
 NSLog(@"JSON: %@", dic);
NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", jsonData2);
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonString);
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"34987598743" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Oc-Merchant-Id"];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationA = [manager PUT:@"http://***/api/rest/addorders" parameters:jsonString success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

      NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

        //[self showStream:carsList];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        // 4
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];
```

so I don't know where is the problem

Answer (score 1):

I've add  `manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializerWithWritingOptions:dic];` and it solved the problem

Comment: Actually "manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]" is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameters as NSDictionary and the manager will handle the serialisation.

```
  AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationA = [manager PUT:@"http://***/api/rest/addorders" parameters: dic success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { 


    }
```

The method signature for PUT is:

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)PUT:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(void ( ^ ) ( AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , id responseObject ))success failure:(void ( ^ ) ( AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error ))failure;
```

So you must pass the **NSDictioanry** instead of **NSString**.Check the request serialiser if is initialised.